# How to alter an empty URL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my webpage from `mysite.com/en/home`, whereas the URI is `mysite.com`.

I tried a lot of things with routes.php, none of those worked:

```
$route['(:any)/'] = 'pages/view/$1/home';
$route[''] = 'home';
$route[''] = 'en';
```

Is this only obtainable by .htaccess? And if so, how can I do it so that it only affects mysite.com, or mysite.com/en queries.

Since the other URL's are like mysite.com/en/about , I don't want to mess them into `mysite.com/en/home/about`

### p.s.

I have the following rule to convert `mysite.com/x/y` to `mysite.com/index.php/x/y` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

could it be the case that this rule is conflicting with others?

Thanks for any help.

### Edit:

Ok, to try Diego Camacho's answer, I created an empty CI project, set the base url in `config.php`, then made the -only- two rules in routes.php as these:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Site';
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
```

and added this function to pages.php (controller):

```
    public function view($arg)
{
    if(!$arg)
    {
        echo "no argument";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "argument = $arg";
    }
}
```

So now, I expect it to work like this:

`http://localhost/ci/index.php/` -> no argument
`http://localhost/ci/index.php/abc` -> arg = abc

but instead, it returns these:

`http://localhost/ci/index.php/` ->

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Pages::view()
>
> Filename: controllers/pages.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: arg
>
> Filename: controllers/pages.php
>
> Line Number: 28
>
> no argument

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/abc
```

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `route.php` file does not redirects, it just "replaces" (in matter of CodeIgniter) routes whereas  `redirect()` does real redirect (change of URL)

Comment: For some reason it made sense to change "" to "home" :) Apparently it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to route your pages to your main controller, so that your main controller can load your home page. example

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Site';
```

Controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
 }

 public function index() {
    $this->home();
 }

 public function home() {
    $this->load->view('content/home');
 }
```

Comment: Yess. I will literally cry joys of tears if I finally have a system where I can make my URL - redirects with PHP. Thanks, man. I will accept your answer as soon as I fix my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I guess I solved the problem. I needed to make the routes.php file like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
```

Comment: nice. glad i could help a bit